# How to hardcode an URL to Digg Digg Facebook like button?

Tags: php, facebook, nginx, wordpress

I'm using [Digg Digg plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/digg-digg/) (which is Open Source, [Github here](https://github.com/bufferapp/diggdigg)) to show a floating social bar on my blog. It's working fine.

But I want to edit it so that if people click on the "Like" button, instead of the post being liked, I want my facebook page to be liked.

I understand that I need to change the dynamic URL used by the plugin to a hardcoded one. I looked up the plugin functions and found the following file named [dd-class.php](https://github.com/bufferapp/diggdigg/blob/master/digg-digg/include/dd-class.php)

I made the following changes in line 501:

Original

```
const BASEURL = "<script src=\"//connect.facebook.net/FACEBOOK_LOCALE/all.js#xfbml=1\"></script><fb:like href=\"VOTE_URL\" FACEBOOK_SEND FACEBOOK_SHOW_FACE VOTE_BUTTON_DESIGN ></fb:like>";
```

Edited to

```
const BASEURL = "<script src=\"//connect.facebook.net/FACEBOOK_LOCALE/all.js#xfbml=1\"></script><fb:like href=\"http://www.facebook.com/mypage\" FACEBOOK_SEND FACEBOOK_SHOW_FACE VOTE_BUTTON_DESIGN ></fb:like>";
```

This should work. But it is still taking the post URL. Can someone please guide me. :(
I'm stuck.

*Just FYI: My WP runs on Nginx and [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/). I was wondering if Varnish is the culprit. So I tried to bypass Varnish too. But the problem persists, so most probably not a Varnish issue. I don't have any other caching plugin at work.*

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want that you must edit the file digg-digg.php instead the dd-class.php

So search inside the function dd_hook_wp_content() and edit (mine is in line 43):

```
//$postlink = get_permalink($id); //get post link
```

to this:

```
$postlink = 'http://www.facebook.com/mypage';
```

I hope this help you.

Notice that if you are working in localhost the Like button will not show because facebook need a dot to recognised as a valid url. So:

```
http://localhost/mysite.com/?p=1#comments
```

will not work but:

```
http://localhost.com/mysite.com/?p=1#comments
```

yes :)

You will see it for example when you work with wordpress

Have fun and voted me pls if help it you!